# Postfix how to triggering my script when outgoing email status is sent?

Tags: linux, postfix

I want to run a program when postfix has successfully sent out a mail (local or remote).
I would like to pass the headers to program and if possible also the destination ip or address (exclude spam filter delivery).

I just have an idea: Delivery Status Notification processing via uniqe transport program, but I'd prefer the above.

My goal is to be recorded lifetime (events) of email: it came, it went out (from, to, subject, datetime, message id, message status: bounce, sent). I would only need the state of the outgoing mail, because incoming  and bounce program is working.

It is possible to trigger a program (similar to a transport pipe/spawn) or DSN "cheat" stay?

Thanks in advance for any reply!

Answer (score 1):

This is only for logging message headers.

By default postix already logs most of this information, though not in one line. It doesn't, however, log the subject or message-id. We can add that in by using [`header_checks 5`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html).
Note: for all mail and not just outgoing, use [`header_checks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#header_checks) instead of [`smtp_header_checks`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtp_header_checks).

---

```
#main.cf
smtp_header_checks = regexp:$config_directory/header-logging.cf


#header-logging.cf
/^subject:/      INFO
/^Subject:/      INFO
/^Message-Id:/   INFO
```

---

These messages will be logged to syslog in the facility specified by [`syslog_facility`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#syslog_facility) `(default: mail)`.

```
Apr  9 15:37:25 mta-msa postfix/smtps/smtpd[14688]: DA75A231C600: client=192-0-2-5.example.com[192.0.2.5], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=foo
Apr  9 15:37:25 mta-msa postfix/cleanup[14686]: DA75A231C600: message-id=<000401d07315$bf0ea5a0$3d2bf0e0$@example.com>
Apr  9 15:37:25 mta-msa postfix/qmgr[14653]: DA75A231C600: from=<foo@example.com>, size=6495, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  9 15:37:26 mta-msa postfix/smtp[14675]: DA75A231C600: info: header Subject: RE: please email as you leave
Apr  9 15:37:26 mta-msa postfix/smtp[14675]: DA75A231C600: info: header Message-ID: <000401d07315$bf0ea5a0$3d2bf0e0$@example.com>
Apr  9 15:37:26 mta-msa postfix/smtp[14675]: DA75A231C600: to=<bar@example.org>, relay=mx.example.org[198.51.100.0]:25, delay=0.65, relays=0.01/0/0.33/0.31, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 1tnx2ya0mh-1 Message accepted for delivery)
Apr  9 15:37:26 mta-msa postfix/qmgr[14653]: DA75A231C600: removed
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with something that is inserted into the postfix processing pipeline [like amavisd-new does.](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/README.postfix.html)

In short, postfix is configured to have a new service in postfix's `master.conf`. that service will be a small program that saves a copy of the messages and then re-inserts the messages into postfix.